# Batch Resize Multiple Images in InDesign Document from Placed MS Word Content

Tags: adobe-indesign, batch-processing

**Problem:**

When I place an entire Word document that includes text and image, the images do not respect the margins and resize automatically, so I have to manually resize them.

**Desired Solution(s):**

- I would like the images to respect the margin width when placing an entire Word document.
- Alternatively, I would like a way to batch resize all images to a maximum width.

**Anything that involves manually placing images (like the first answer below) doesn't solve my problem at all.**

---

For some background, here is the process that I am currently doing manually for every single image in the document. Here is the image after placing the entire Word document, you will notice that it is outside the margin.

[image]

I click the container, change the width to 28p (after selecting the icon to constrain proportions). You'll notice that the image is the same size and is now only partially viewed through the container.

[image]

Then I click again to select the image itself, and change the width to 28p as well.

[image]

I'd be happy with any solution to this problem. Maybe I have set my margins and properties incorrectly?  Or maybe this is a solution that requires using scripting?

And again, I'm trying to automate this process, so anything that requires clicking for every single image isn't an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend changing the .docx file to .zip, opening that up and copying everything from the images folder into a separate images folder with your .indd document. That will a) let you access the not-messed-with-by-Word originals, and b) let you use Bridge or your OS navigator to select and place them. This just makes things a lot cleaner.

Also, just as a general rule, never place an image by clicking on the page. Always click and drag unless you know the dimensions are correct before you start.

There are several ways to go about handling or avoiding this problem on an image-by-image basis.

- If you turn on Auto-Fit in the Control Panel, images will resize as you change the frame.
- Holding `Ctl-Shift` while you click and drag the frame will automatically scale the frame and the image proportionally.
- If you select all the images (or a bunch of them) in Bridge, right-click and choose `Place > in InDesign` you'll get a loaded cursor (or "Place Gun" as it's lovingly referred to in some circles). Click and drag out the frame size you need for each image. The image will automatically scale to fit the frame as you drag, and if you have Smart Guides enabled, you'll be able to easily place identically sized images on each page.

Comment: DUDE!!!!!! The zip thing.. had no idea. I've waisted so much time weeding through Word files for images. All this time I just needed to change the suffix, decompress, and find the "media" folder. You just saved me hours, literally. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! An amazing number of file formats are zipped XML collections, like ePub. All of the MS Office 'x' formats are that way.

Comment: I knew about ePub but had no clue about the .docx though. Thanks again.

Comment: I should clarify: I'm placing the entire Word document at once, pictures and all.  Any solution that involves manually placing all of the images kinda defeats the automation angle that I was going for.

Comment: How do I resize multiple images in a document? I appreciate this answer, but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: If you place an entire Word doc with images all in one go, you're working directly against the basic architecture of the program. Anything you do from that point will be slower and more difficult. The solution is to build a workflow that uses the software, not try to bludgeon the software into fitting your preconceived workflow.